# Play DTMF tones in outgoing call using Twilio

Tags: rest, twilio, voice, ivr, dtmf

In my [Twilio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilio)-based application I create outgoing calls via the Twilio [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API.

When the target side responds, I put him/her to the recently-created conference.

How can I play a certain set of DTMF tones before putting him/her to the conference?

The responding side is a certain system which accepts DTMF tones, and I need to play some set of the digits.

I have read the documentation, but I did not find way to do this.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two different ways to do this depending on your situation.

One option is to use the [sendDigits](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional) parameter when making your outbound phone call.  Specifying sendDigits tells Twilio to dial a set of DTMF tones once your outbound call has connected.  [This is an example that includes the sendDigits parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#example-3).

Another option is to use the `<Play>` verb includes a parameter named [`digits`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play#attributes-digits) which lets you tell Twilio it should play a set of DTMF tones.  [This is an example of using <Play> with the digits parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play#examples-2).