# Press the button during a call in twilio?

Tags: php, api, twilio

How emulate press the button during a call to put the incoming call to the extension number of the employee in twilio (php)?

API or smth else, if you know.
Thank you.

Example. Our sub-division call to central office and then our system must send "something pressed buttons"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twilio - Outgoing call - play DTMF tones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561006/twilio-outgoing-call-play-dtmf-tones)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [sendDigits](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number) attribute when dialing your number.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number sendDigits="1231">888-123-1234</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Adelphia. Can I send digits when somebody call me?

Comment: Just read your comment about Play command with digits attribute.

Comment: Yep, you sure can. You can use Twiml's <play> verb or if you're using the JS Client Lib, there are options for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I did this when setting up my Twilio apartment front door control. I got the right mp3 files for each button and simply played them back. I used this message [twimlet](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/message):

```
http://twimlets.com/message?Message[0]=http://jetcityorange.com/dtmf/DTMF-9.mp3&Message[1]=Thank+You+For+Using+The+Callbox
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to play DTMF tones in Twilio without playing any MP3s. Infact,  since you're using the PLAY verb already you can just add a "digits" attribute, no MP3 required. `<Play digits="123"></Play>` will play the dial tone for 123.

Comment: Good to know! It was a quick weekend hack. Trying to get into the flow of actually answering questions on Stack instead of just reading them. You're solution is more useful. If I ever go back to add functionality to my door system I'll use the digits attribute on the play verb.